# How do you combine two data frames on two values and add an extra column containing a boolean for if the row appeared in the second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two csv files, one with an ID, a year and some other stats and then I have another csv file with just the name and year. The first is just a collection of all users, years and the corresponding stats and the other is for winners of an award and the year that they won it. I'm trying to combine the two and have the result as an extra column in the first data set showing a boolean value for if they won an award that year or not.

e.g [embiijo01,2018-19,...] and [embiijo01,2018-19] would turn into [embiijo01,2018-19,...,1]

Comment: please add proper data and then the expected output

Comment: You left merge, dropping duplicates in the right DataFrame on merge keys (so that the result is guaranteed to be the same size as the original). Specify `indicator=True` and then `'both'` is 1 and `'left_only'` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.merge(csv_1, csv_2, on = 'ID/Name/User/identification of the person', how = 'left')
```

Should be able to just do simple if statement and append or add column for the boolean.

https://towardsdatascience.com/why-and-how-to-use-merge-with-pandas-in-python-548600f7e738

Comment: Link is a pretty comprehensive understanding of how to merge datasets